# How can I use the TSQL commands Top and IN together in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The sample code that I am referring to is as follows:

```
SELECT top(3) * FROM AcceptorRequests
WHERE Terminal IN ('70270191','70347395')
ORDER BY Id DESC
```

But it works for only one terminal number. I want to display three end records for each terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
;with cte
as
(
SELECT  *,row_number() over (partition by terminal order by id desc) as rownum  FROM AcceptorRequests 
WHERE Terminal IN ('70270191','70347395')
)
select * from cte where rownum<=3
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use `union all` :

```
SELECT top(3) * 
FROM AcceptorRequests 
WHERE Terminal = '70270191'
UNION ALL
SELECT top(3) * 
FROM AcceptorRequests 
WHERE Terminal = '70347395'
order by Id desc
```